# AngularJS Error: [$injector:nomod] when trying to load 'templates'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I'm following a tutorial right here: https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/

I'm at the part of "Wiring Everything Up". I'm still new at this and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'templates' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=templates

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flapperNews due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module templates due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'templates' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=templates
minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-4d9f3d92a489ec19b3256abf7e10c0fd.js?body=1:64:12
module/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-4d9f3d92a489ec19b3256abf7e10c0fd.js?body=1:1775:1
ensure@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-4d9f3d92a489ec19b3256abf7e10c0fd.js?body=1:1699:38
```

I'm pretty sure I've put it in application.js right after "angular". I'm adding up my controllers here, too. The structure is the same in the tutorial in my link. Thanks in advance!

// app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                return posts.getAll();
            }]
        }
    }).state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

// mainCtrl.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$posts',
    function($scope){
        $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

        $scope.posts = posts.posts;

        $scope.addPost = function(){
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
                upvotes: 0
            });
            $scope.title = '';
            $scope.link = '';

            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
                upvotes: 0,
                comments: [
                    {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                    {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
                ]
            });
        };

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };


    }]);
```

// postsCtrl.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        '$stateParams',
        'posts',

    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){

        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

        $scope.addComment = function(){
            if($scope.body === '') { return; }
            $scope.post.comments.push({
                body: $scope.body,
                author: 'user',
                upvotes: 0
            });
            $scope.body = '';
        };


    }]);
```

// application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require_tree .
```

//application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="flapperNews">
<head>
  <title>FlapperNews</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `require`:

```
//= angular-rails-templates
```

should be

```
//= require angular-rails-templates
```

BTW - you need to specify the order of javascript files to be loaded. If at any point assets pipeline will decide to load your controller before your app, you will get angular exception, so you should add `//= require app` statement to your controller file as well.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: @bitfrost41 - No worries, once i spent two hours looking for missing `=` in those comments.

Comment: Cool. I'm gonna finish this tutorial now and this probably is not my last question here. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all of your javascript into your index.html page, so your index.html should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="flapperNews">
<head>
  <title>FlapperNews</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- this could be a bower location or a straight download-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/angular.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/templates.js></script>
etc.


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those will be added automatically by assets pipeline in development and will be merged into  single file in production.

Comment: oh - i see - I dont use rails so not sure how that works

Comment: Yes, he's right. It's in my asset pipeline. Anyway, it's been answered by him above. :D